# How to update Room database row using a LiveData<T> object?

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm want to update my UI and database entry simultaneously. For this I am using an OnChanged observer in my code (snippet below). However, update() expects a regular object and not LiveData<>. If I change the update() method to take in LiveData, I get an error saying I need to annotate is as `@Entity`, which does not work either. How am I meant to use update() to update the single field of the given userProfile in my database?

```
private LiveData<UserProfile> userProfile;

...

protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    // Initialize the dao used to return the size of active/inactive users in the users table
    final WorksideDatabase mDb = WorksideDatabase.getInstance(this);
    userProfile = mDb.userProfileDao().getUser(id);


    userProfile.observe(
        UserServiceStatus.this,
        new Observer<UserProfile>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable UserProfile sections) {

                ...

                mDb.userProfileDao().update(userProfile);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDit - Preview:

[image]

Comment: I don't quite get what you are trying to do. You get something from the database and want to immediately write it back?!

Comment: Your view layer should not hold references to databases and logic referred to it.
Consider using MVVM pattern, where your LiveData will be created in ViewModel, which will call an interactor (logic-layer), which will interact with databases, repositories (data-layer)

Comment: @MarkusPenguin I don't necessarily want to update the database immediately - that can be done `onBackPressed()`. I just don't know how I am meant to pass the new value (which I set using `userProfile.getValue().setStatus(false);`) to the database row.

Comment: @Steyrix okay so that honestly has nothing to do with the problem at hand, but at least it takes 3x code to do the same thing. He doesn't need any Interactors for this.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I just want author to note, that he should not use such a simple and unclear approach in production.

Comment: Having both Interactors AND Repositories at the same time is equally unclear, it just takes more code. One could argue that people shouldn't be using multiple Activities in the same app just to show a second layout in production, yet that doesn't stop anyone from doing it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value from `LiveData` (in your case: to get the `UserProfile` from `LiveData<UserProfile>`) you need to use the `getValue()` method. Also make sure you to the update on a background thread.

```
private LiveData<UserProfile> userProfile;

@Override
public void onChanged(@Nullable UserProfile sections) {
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Option 1: use method parameter
            mDb.userProfileDao().update(sections);

            // Option 2: get the value
            mDb.userProfileDao().update(userProfile.getValue());
        }
    });
}
```

I don't see why you'd write an object that you fetched from the database back immediately, but with the above solution you are able to do it. You'll probably only want to write the object back to the database after you changed it.

Comment: `mDb.userProfileDao().update(sections);` gives the error `Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time`. I tried to run `mDb.userProfileDao().update(userProfile.getValue());` in onBackPressed() as well with the same error. Where should I run update()? Or do I have to call a ViewModel object to do that?

Comment: The user may decide to change the status, but instead exit the application instead of pressing back. It would be ideal if the new status value was still saved to the database should that happen.

Comment: The simplest approach would be to wrap the call to `update` in an `AsyncTask`. In case you are wondering why you are allowed to  call `getUser()` on the main thread: it's because you are getting an instance of `LiveData`.

Comment: To solve that, you need to execute that write on a background thread.

Comment: Thank you both. I am using an AsyncTask in both onChanged() cases (switch flipped active/inactive) and the database is updated - even if I choose to close the app and come back, which is what I initially wanted.